# Creation of dbus interfaces in Bluez

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, a2dp

A question regarding the creation of dbus interfaces such as

org.bluez.Audio,
org.bluez.AudioSource

appearing on d-feet debugger.

Does the host running Bluez(For eg. Laptop) create an interface **org.bluez.AudioSource** for a remote device behaving as a Bluetooth A2DP source?

So similarly how to create an **org.bluez.AudioSink** interface on any bluetooth phone for example to make it behave as an A2DP receiver? In that case should the host(for eg. Laptop) create an AudioSink interface for interacting with the bluez on the phone side?

Comment: Maybe http://nex.scrapping.cc/articles/linux-bluez-a2dp-alsa.html will help you. If that does not help you try #bluez-users at freenode. (Channel taken from the post)

Comment: I enabled audio sink service on my host, it should be now recognized by the device to CONNECT to my A2DP_SINK service right?

Comment: I do not know. Ask at #bluez-users at freenode. http://webchat.freenode.net/

Answer (score 1):

in C to create A2DP connection u can use these parameters

```
DBusMessage *msg;   
msg = dbus_message_new_method_call("org.bluez",btadrr_path,"org.bluez.AudioSource","Connect");
```

here btaddre_path is my bluetooth device path which is already paired...

in Python

```
manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"), "org.bluez.Manager")

adapter = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", manager.DefaultAdapter()), "org.bluez.Adapter");

audiosrc = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", adapter.FindDevice(bdaddr)), "org.bluez.AudioSource");

audiosrc.Connect()
```